# how to find the direct and indirect relation between the strings?

Tags: python, string, search

I have one list and one dictionary that contain combinations of strings and their respective properties. list contains the list of combination of states and the dictionary contains the properties of those combinations:

```
stateInputs = ['Uttar Pradesh-Uttrakhand', 'Delhi-Uttrakhand', 'Uttar Pradesh-Delhi']
stateProperties = {
    'Uttar Pradesh-Uttrakhand':(100,200),
    'Delhi-Uttrakhand':(210,300),
    'Uttar Pradesh-Delhi':(399,210)
}
```

I have written a program that can read these properties by the name but I want to make it more dynamic, for example, if I replace the state names like from `Delhi-Uttrakhand` to `Uttrakhand-Delhi`(kind of indirect search), then also it should be able to tell the properties. My approach is like this:

```
stateInputs = ['Uttar Pradesh-Uttrakhand', 'Delhi-Uttrakhand', 'Uttar Pradesh-Delhi']
stateProperties = {
    'Uttar Pradesh-Uttrakhand': (100, 200),
    'Delhi-Uttrakhand': (210, 300),
    'Uttar Pradesh-Delhi': (399, 210)
}

for i in stateInputs:
    print(stateProperties[i][1])
```

But this program doesn't work with reverse string combination, can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that can help you here is `Levenshtein Distance` which is implemented https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy

This will also take care of minor spelling mistakes

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

def get_val(state):
    k = sorted(stateProperties.keys(), key=lambda x: fuzz.token_sort_ratio(x, state))[-1]
    return stateProperties[k][1]
```

The advantage of this would be that even if you change the order of states or make spelling mistake you will still get the desired answer. For ex.

```
get_val('Uttrakhand-Delhi')
get_val('Delhi-Uttrakhand')
get_val('Delhi-Utrahand')
```

All will give `300`.

This makes your code more resilient and production ready.

Comment: Most welcome, thanks to SeatGeek for implementing the neat algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

You could create the reverse combination by splitting on `-` and re-joining, and checking that combination as well. You can use `if key in dictionary` to check which of the two combinations exists.

```
for stateInput in stateInputs:
    reversedInput = '-'.join(stateInput.split('-')[::-1])
    if stateInput in stateProperties:
        print(stateProperties[stateInput][1])
    elif reversedInput in stateProperties:
        print(stateProperties[reversedInput][1])
```

Creating the `reversedInput` value works in three steps:

- `stateInput.split('-')`: split the string by hyphens and store the parts in a list (e.g. `['Delhi', 'Uttrakhand']`)
- `stateInput.split('-')[::-1]`: reverse the list (e.g. `['Uttrakhand', 'Delhi']`)
- `'-'.join(stateInput.split('-')[::-1])`: join all items in the list with a hyphen (e.g. `'Uttrakhand-Delhi'`)

Note that this code only works for states with one hyphen in the name. If you want more hyphens and arbitrary combinations, you should take a look at the [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) method for generating all combinations.

Comment: hey, that's a very detailed answer. Thanks man